# Realm Database Relationship

Tags: database, relationship, realm

I need help in realm database relationship for Swift 2.0. I have two data models with one to many relationship of category and expense.

```
class Category: Object {
  dynamic variable categoryid = 0
  dynamic variable category_name = ""
}

class Expense: Object {
  dynamic var expenseid = 0
  dynamic var expensename = "" 
  dynamic var category: Category? = nil
}
```

For this i need to filter my result of expenses for a particular category

```
let records = try! Realm().objects(Expense).filter(??????)
```

How can I filter the records for just the selected category?

Also, I am maintaining a category thorough which I want to filter my results rather than the table index.  Should I set the `categoryid` from one view to another through the `prepareForSegue` function?

Comment: To your side question: You can use `prepareForSegue` to pass around data between view controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your `Expense` objects by retrieving first a given `Category` object and using that in your query:

```
let category = …
let records = try! Realm().objects(Expense).filter("category = ?", category)
```

Comment: Thanks Marius, but its still giving the error "expected member name or constructor call after type name", how should I resolve this, can you suggest any project on git for this. Also, how does realm actually maintains the relationship. I am from an Oracle background and have a habit of defining relationship like tableA.id = tableB.id, so would like to understand that.

Comment: You might be able to address the error by writing `Expense.self` instead of just the type name. This is usually just needed with Swift, when the type is passed with other arguments alongside, so I guess, that you're calling another method?

Comment: To your side question: Realm's core has a native concept of links, which works much like pointers.